# Given a 2D array of doubles, how to calculate the best combination of chosen cells (only 1 cell chosen per col and per row) w/o using brute force?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, optimization

Given a 2D array like this:

```
double temp_arr[3][3]={{0.1,0.5,0.2},
                       {0.0,0.0,0.4},
                       {0.0,0.2,0.7}};
```

I have to select a combination, where every row and every col must have exactly 1 cell selected, ie. {temp_arr[0][0],temp_arr[1][1],temp_arr[2][2]} etc. How do I determine which combination will give me:

1. the most number of non-zero values
2. (if the combinations have the same number of non-zero values) the largest sum

Is there a way to do this without using brute force? I am currently using brute force, but the number of permutations grows very quickly as the array size increases, so I am hoping there is a more efficient way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a concrete idea either, but an index array together with [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) might help you simplify the brute force approach – if you are not yet using them anyway...

Comment: This is known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). One solution is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). There are other algorithms mentioned in the articles.

Comment: @user3386109 This is exactly what I need :) Thanks so much!